# Get subcollection from firestore from same object - React typescript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-typescript

My interface looks like this:

**Interface react:**

```
export interface UserTask {
    assignee: String;
    date: String;
}


export interface TaskData {
    id: String;
    taskName: string;
    taskIcon: string;
    taskLog: UserTask[] 
}
```

**Firebase Data model (Structure):**

[image: Firebase screenshot]

```
- taskData (Main Collection)
    - taskIcon (fields)
    - taskName (fields)
    - taskLog (sub-collection) 
        - assignee  (fields)
        - date (fields)
```

**React code to get firestore data:**

```
import { firestore } from '../firebase';
```

...

```
function toTaskData(doc): TaskData {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        throw new Error("TaskData  not found!");
    } else {

        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()  } as TaskData;
    }
  }


  const getTaskData = async() => {
    const taskDataRef = firestore.collection('taskData');
    await taskDataRef.get().then(({docs}) => {
      setTaskData(docs.map(toTaskData));
    });
  }
```

**Response JSON from firestore:**

[image]

I am only getting an response which contains an array of the `taskName` and `taskIcon` and not the subcollection `taskLog`, my question is how to I retrieve the subcollection or map it to UserTask array?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries are **shallow**: when you fetch a document you don't fetch the the data contained in any of its linked subcollections.

If you want to get a Firestore Document together with all the documents from one of its subcollection, you need to do two fetches: one fetch for the "parent" doc and one for all the docs of the subcollection.

For example, you can do something along the following lines, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const taskDataRef = firestore.collection('taskData');
const querySnapshot = await taskDataRef.get();

const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.collection('taskLog').get());

const querySnapshotsArray = Promise.all(promises);

querySnapshotsArray.forEach(querySnapshot => {
   
   // Do something with the querySnapshot
   // e.g. querySnapshot.docs....
   // or querySnapshot.forEach(...)

});
```

---

If you want to combine the data of one parent (a `taskData` doc) together with all the children `taskLog` docs, note that `Promise.all()` returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises **which is in the same order than** the input Array. In other words, `querySnapshotsArray` has the same order than `promises`.

---

Note that doing so will cost the read of ALL the taskData docs and ALL the taskLog documents from ALL the `taskLog` subcollections. It may be less exepensive to organize your front end in such a way the subcollections are only fetched on demand (e.g. if the user clicks on a button or expands a section, etc...)

Comment: I get that would you recommend making a array called taskLogs instead of creating them in subcollection? I understand in terms of read, but Im thinking of extending the functionality later on maybe filtering search by date and by users.

Comment: "would you recommend making a array called taskLogs instead of creating them in subcollection" => This is difficult to anwser with the available amount of information. It highly depends on the queries you want to do from your front end. For example, you may be interested by filtering the taskLogs by date for a specific taskData => subcollection makes sebnse in this case... Also note that there is a size limit of 1 MiB for a Firestore doc => If your taskLogs Array contains a lot of elements, you might reach the limit.

Comment: Yes, thats why I went with this approach. If its not much to ask can you extend the querySnapshot part? I'm getting error on `querySnapshotsArray.forEach(doc => {` maybe limit the documents to 5 sorted by date so the query doesn't read many document?

Comment: `querySnapshotsArray` is not an array of `DocumentSnapshot`s but of `querySnapshot`s. This is why you need to loop twice: on `querySnapshotsArray` and then on each `querySnapshot`.

Comment: @CookieMonster Hi, did you have time to look at the answer?

Comment: Thanks for following up, yes and I ended up using one document and creating an array of user tasks in it. I think it might be a better solution mainly to reduce the document reads